# Scroll TableView inside ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I have a `tableView` inside a `scrollView`.

[image]

I want when I scroll `tableView`, the outer `scrollView` will also scroll.

Currently, when I scroll `tableView`, the outer `scrollView` not scroll.

[image]

So how to do this?

Comment: set tableview scrollEnabled to NO, and calculate again contain view height to fit tableview height

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @ABáo

Comment: How much content will you show in the `scrollView`, can't you simple add a `headerView` to the `tableView`?

Comment: Here is just a sample, in my real project, it content a container view which can be switched to 4 modes. Content in `scrollView` is depend on the `tableView` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

//Declare the view which is going to be added as scrolling view, for instance

```
let requiredView = UIScrollView()
```

//Add your required view as subview of tableview backgroundView view like as

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIView() 
tableView.backgroundView?.addSubview(requiredView)
```

//After that control the frame of requiredHeaderView in scrollViewDidScroll delegate method like

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
         let per:CGFloat = 60 //percentage of required view to move on while moving collection view
                let deductValue = CGFloat(per / 100 * requiredView.frame.size.height)
                let offset = (-(per/100)) * (scrollView.contentOffset.y)
                let value = offset - deductValue                   
                self.requiredView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(1.0, value)
        }
```

Comment: When I scroll tableView, the outer scrollView not scroll.

Comment: If your not set the contentSize for the scrollView try to set like this requiredView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 500)

Comment: I've already set the contentSize for the scrollView in storyBoard.

Comment: post code about how you tried. That way I can extend my help.

Comment: where you tried my answer?, scrollViewDidScroll method contains different of my posted answer. In my answer "value" in scrollViewDidScroll method is the contentOffset.y value to move the scrollview. That way you can scroll the scroll view accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123313/discussion-between-khuong-and-vishnuvardhan).